# Calculate total price (not a single group)

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'm trying to calculate the total amount below the code commented. When I uncomment the code I'm getting
and I'm getting the error 'Not a single group function'. I can't seem to figure out the fix and hoping someone could tell me how to fix this issue.

Below iis my setup and test CASE. Thanks in advance to all who answer.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY  HH24:MI:SS.FF';

 ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

CREATE TABLE customers 
(CUSTOMER_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) AS
SELECT 1, 'Faith', 'Aaron' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Lisa', 'Saladino' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Bonnie', 'Winterbottom' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Beth', 'Zanzone' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Sandy', 'Herring' FROM DUAL;

ALTER TABLE customers 
ADD CONSTRAINT customers_pk PRIMARY KEY (customer_id);

CREATE TABLE items 
(PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_NAME, PRICE) AS
SELECT 100, 'Presto 6-quart Pressure Cooker', 79.99 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101, 'Cuisinart 8-quart Pressure Cooker', 111.99 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 102, 'Farberware 3-quart Pressure Cooker', 49.99 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 103, 'Farberware 6-quart Pressure Cooker', 89.29 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 104, 'Farberware 8-quart Pressure Cooker', 105.99 FROM DUAL;

ALTER TABLE items 
ADD CONSTRAINT items_pk PRIMARY KEY (product_id);

create table purchases(
  ORDER_ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
  customer_id   number, 
  PRODUCT_ID NUMBER, 
  QUANTITY NUMBER, 
  purchase_date timestamp
);

ALTER TABLE purchases 
ADD CONSTRAINT order_pk PRIMARY KEY (order_id);

ALTER TABLE purchases ADD CONSTRAINT customers_fk FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers(customer_id);

ALTER TABLE purchases ADD CONSTRAINT items_fk FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCT_ID) REFERENCES items(product_id);

insert  into purchases (customer_id, product_id, quantity, purchase_date) 
SELECT 3, 102, 4,TIMESTAMP '2022-12-22 21:44:35' + NUMTODSINTERVAL ( LEVEL * 2, 'DAY') FROM    dual
CONNECT BY  LEVEL <= 15 UNION ALL 
select 1, 101,3, date '2023-03-29' + level * interval '2' day from dual
          connect by level <= 12
union all
select 2, 101,2, date '2023-01-15' + level * interval '8' hour from dual
          connect by level <= 15
union all
select 2, 102,2,date '2023-04-13' + level * interval '1 1' day to hour from dual
          connect by level <= 11
union all
select 3, 101,2, date '2023-02-01' + level * interval '1 05:03' day to minute from dual
          connect by level <= 10
union all
select 3, 101,1, date '2023-04-22' + level * interval '23' hour from dual
          connect by level <= 23
union all
select 3, 100,1,  date '2022-03-01' + level * interval '1 00:23:05' day to second from dual
          connect by level <= 15
union all
select 3, 101,1,  date '2022-03-01' + level * interval '1 00:23:05' day to second from dual
          connect by level <= 15
union all
select 4, 102,1, date '2023-01-01' + level * interval '5' hour from dual
          connect by level <= 60;

/* Total quantity purchased each item */

with prep (product_id, tot_quantity) as 
(
   select 
      product_id, 
      sum(quantity)
    from   purchases
    group  by product_id
  )
SELECT  
     p.product_id, 
     I.product_name,
  tot_quantity,
/*
     sum(tot_quantity * i.PRICE) 
"TOTAL_AMT"
*/
 FROM prep p
JOIN items i ON i.product_id = p.product_id  
ORDER BY tot_quantity desc,
product_id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because all non-aggregated items have to be put into the `group by` clause (line #12):

```
SQL> WITH
  2     prep (product_id, tot_quantity)
  3     AS
  4        (  SELECT product_id, SUM (quantity)
  5             FROM purchases
  6         GROUP BY product_id)
  7    SELECT p.product_id,
  8           I.product_name,
  9           tot_quantity,
 10           SUM (tot_quantity * i.PRICE) "TOTAL_AMT"
 11      FROM prep p JOIN items i ON i.product_id = p.product_id
 12  GROUP BY p.product_id, i.product_name, tot_quantity
 13  ORDER BY tot_quantity DESC, product_id;

PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME                       TOT_QUANTITY  TOTAL_AMT
---------- ---------------------------------- ------------ ----------
       102 Farberware 3-quart Pressure Cooker          142    7098,58
       101 Cuisinart 8-quart Pressure Cooker           124   13886,76
       100 Presto 6-quart Pressure Cooker               15    1199,85

SQL>
```